# RegGetValue returned data type differs from the data type mentioned in admx file for the gpo setting

Tags: c++, windows, group-policy, gpo

For the gpo setting: "**Network directories to sync at Logon/Logoff time only**", in the corresponding **UserProfiles.admx** file, datatype is mentioned as REG_EXPAND_SZ:

**< text id="CscSuspendDirectories_Message" valueName="CscSuspendDirs" maxLength="4096" *expandable="true"* />**

(expandable="true" means REG_EXPAND_SZ instead of REG_SZ as mentioned in [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753757(v=ws.10).aspx) )

but i get the data type as REG_SZ when reading that subkey value using [RegGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Am using the statement: `RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, achValue, RRF_RT_ANY, &dataType, NULL, &size);`

*dataType and size are of type DWORD.*

*hKey is pointing to registry key "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System"*

*and achValue is referring to "CscSuspendDirs"*

am getting dataType as 1 (REG_SZ) when the function call returns which differs from what mentioned in admx file for the setting.

How to get the correct data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use `RRF_RT_ANY | RRF_NOEXPAND`in `RegGetValue` method to prevent automatically expand the string to REG_SZ.